# How to find if a point is one of the vertices of a line using postgresSQL query

Tags: postgresql

How to find if a point is one of the vertices of a line using PostgreSQL query and PostGis functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a point is part of a multiline, you can use something like

```
SELECT 
   /* this will count the number of occurrences of the point in the linestring */
   count(
      /* this will be NULL if the point is not equal to the n-th point */
      CASE WHEN st_pointn(g.geom, n) = st_geomfromtext('POINT(10 0)')
           THEN 1
      END
   ) > 0  /* result is TRUE if the point is on the multiline */
FROM (VALUES(st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(0 0,10 0,10 10)'))) g(geom)
   /* this is a table containing all vertex numbers of the linestring */
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, st_numpoints(geom)) n(n);
```